# Error: Image with src "/placeholder.svg" is missing required "width" property

Tags: reactjs, svg, width, next.js13

I am getting this problem when I link this page code with my main page. I'm stuck here, I tried everywhere to solve it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJEDR.png) it shows this error.

```
<Image 
alt="Donghua Image"                                                   
className="rounded-lg object-cover w-full aspect-[6/3] group-hover:opacity-50 transition-opacity"                                                   
height={300}                                                   
src="/placeholder.svg"                                                   
width={400}                                            
/>
```

Pls resolve this error or tell me what to do it

Comment: Could you provide all the code(full component) with imports? There is no problem with that piece of code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.